# First() in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, aggregate-functions

i have data like below. so I would like to group by year, name and the first value of name.

```
year,name,id
2017,AAA,101
2017,AAA,102
2017,AAA,221
2018,BBB,110
2018,BBB,112
2019,CCC,501
2019,CCC,504
```

i would like to get the output like below

```
2017,AAA,101
2018,BBB,110
2019,CCC,501
```

Comment: Please provide more representative data example if row_number in my answer does not work for your data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your data example simple row_number will work:

```
select year,name,id
  from
      (
       select year,name,id, 
              row_number() over(partition by year order by id) rn 
         from mytable
      )s
 where rn=1
```

Comment: I've always wondered, isn't there a huge overhead to using subquery? I have to go through all the rows, and row_number() each row, and order everything, just to take the first, and discard the rest. Having said this, I see no other way to achieve this.

Comment: @SidaZhou Sub-queries in Hive do not necessarily create additional processing stages. Check the plan using EXPLAIN command and you will see, optimizer rewrites query plan if possible, does not matter how many sub-queries have you added.